# How to study the cause and effect relationship between 2 variables?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, causality

I have data from a random sample of hotel bookings. I want to study the cause and effect relationship between number of days in advance that the hotel was booked (or book lag, also called `nday_booking_early`) and the price paid per night for the booking.

Book lag and price vary when the booking is made on the weekend versus a weekday.

How should I study this relationship? Do I need to run multiple regression only, or experimental design as well?

[image]

Comment: Well, please start by explaining what the variable names mean and what they represent.

Comment: @Jim I have updated the variable names. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot study cause and effect because you do not measure confounding variables. I know straight away that income is a confounder: full time employed people are more likely to book on the weekend because that's their free time, and they are more likely to spend more. Maybe "cause-and-effect" is too ambitious. Why not describe the differences you alluded to earlier with simple mean differences in a regression model?

Comment: In addition to @AdamO 's point it is not clear what "run experimental design" means.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to predict "Price per night" by "nday_booking_early" a *simple linear regression* would be sufficient.

In this case, your prediction ŷ ("Price per night") would be predicted by a value of x ("nday_booking_early") that is assigned a coefficient w e), yielding the prediction formula

ŷ = w * x

This would, of course, neglect all the other information in your table. If you want to predict your variable "Price per night" also by "country_code" and/or "check-in_dayname", you would need to run *multiple regression*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have run a multiple regression (price_per_night~Hotel+(checkin_date:n_night)+nday_booking_early). However, there is a correlation between price per night and booking in weekend. nday_booking_early of weekend booking is also higher than weekday. I am confused how to conclude the cause and effect between nday_booking_early and price per night.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "conclude the cause and effect"?  It's not clear where your confusion lies, which makes it difficult to give a helpful answer.

Comment: In regards to "cause and effect", any kind of regression will not give you the cause but merely correlation. Eventually, according to Karl Popper, you cannot _prove_ a hypothesis but only _disprove_ it. IMO your problem is **_multicollinearity_** that will screw up your multiple regression, making machine learning a more ideal approach for your predictions. A good discussion about multicollinearity in "traditional statistics" vs. ML can be found here: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168622/why-is-multicollinearity-not-checked-in-modern-statistics-machine-learning)