# Which threshold should I use for GVIF1/(2⋅df)? (Variance Inflation Factor)

Tags: r, multiple-regression, least-squares, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I'm using the mtcars dataset in R, I used the car packages to estimate the VIF, but since I have factor variables I got the vif table with GVIF and GVIF1/(2⋅df) values, in another question [Which variance inflation factor should I be using: $\text{GVIF}$ or $\text{GVIF}^{1/(2\cdot\text{df})}$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70679/which-variance-inflation-factor-should-i-be-using-textgvif-or-textgvif), John Fox, co-author of https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1992.10475190#.U2jkTFdMzTo, mentioned that they recommend using GVIF^(1/(2*Df)), but I don't know if I should use the rule of thumb of <5 with the standard VIF or I should use another number.

This is my code:

```
mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, {
  vs <- factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  am <- factor(am, labels = c("Automatic", "Manual"))
  cyl  <- ordered(cyl)
  gear <- ordered(gear)
  carb <- ordered(carb)
})

mtcars2$loghp <- log(mtcars2$hp) 


mtcars2 <- mtcars2 %>%  
  dplyr::mutate(cylnum = as.numeric(mtcars2$cyl))%>%  
  dplyr::mutate(cylcat = cut(cylnum, breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
                             labels = c("Cyl_4", "Cyl_6", "Cyl_8")))

mtcars2_lm <- mtcars2[, c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)]
model1 <- lm(mpg ~., data = mtcars2_lm)
vif(model1)
```

|  | GVIF | Df | GVIF^(1/(2*Df)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cyl | 98.027045 | 2 | 3.146563 |
| disp | 57.217057 | 1 | 7.564196 |
| drat | 7.105793 | 1 | 2.665669 |
| wt | 23.490085 | 1 | 4.846657 |
| qsec | 10.731794 | 1 | 3.275942 |
| vs | 7.354487 | 1 | 2.711916 |
| am | 9.936800 | 1 | 3.152269 |
| gear | 50.681013 | 2 | 2.668157 |
| carb | 244.371502 | 5 | 1.733026 |
| loghp | 14.626620 | 1 | 3.824476 |

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Threshold for what?

Comment: For deciding which variables I should delete from my model, I have read that the rule of thumb for continuous variables is 5, so you keep all variables that have a <5 value in its vif score.

Comment: Why do you want to delete variables from your model?

Comment: To prevent the multicollinearity problem

Comment: Please read over [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/168622/28500) for reasons why you might not need to worry about VIF much at all. High multicollinearity might lead to high-magnitude covariances among coefficient estimates, but for a predictive model that's not really a problem.

Comment: Also keep in mind that, yes, you might decrease your variance by getting stable coefficient estimates, but that could be at the expense of biasing your model to discount a predictor that does matter, perhaps so much bias that the decrease in variance is not worth the increase in bias.